# Installing bower packages after running yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, dependencies, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I'm having trouble getting this to work and even finding solutions through google on how to make it work.

Going to Bowers site shows they have a programatic API that looks like I should be able to run it in node, of course I can however it's not obeying my .bowerrc file and installing them into my dev folder created by yeoman.

Does this have something to do with the way yeoman works? Are the files and directories not quite available yet until after it's logged done()?

Here is my index.js

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var bower = require('bower');


var FoprojectGenerator = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  sayHello: function(){
    console.log(this.yeoman);
  },
  scaffoldFolders: function(){
    this.mkdir("working");
    this.mkdir("working/assets");
    this.mkdir("working/assets/sass");
    this.mkdir("working/assets/coffee");
    this.mkdir('dev');
  },
  copyMainFiles: function(){
    this.copy("_index.html", "working/index.html");
    this.copy("_gruntfile.js", "Gruntfile.js");
    this.copy("_package.json", "package.json");
    this.copy("_bower.json", "bower.json");
    this.copy("_.bowerrc", ".bowerrc");
    this.copy("assets/sass/_site.sass", "working/assets/sass/site.sass");
    this.copy("assets/sass/_mixins.sass", "working/assets/sass/_mixins.sass");
    this.copy("assets/sass/_normalize.sass", "working/assets/sass/_normalize.sass");
    this.copy("assets/coffee/_scripts.coffee", "working/assets/coffee/scripts.coffee");
  },
  installDependencies: function(){
    var done = this.async();
    console.log("\nInstalling Node Dependencies\n");
    this.npmInstall("", function(){
      console.log("\nInstalling Bower Packages\n");
      bower.commands
      .install()
      .on('end', function(){
        done();
      });
    });
  }
});

module.exports = FoprojectGenerator;
```

Like I said it runs great, but it installs it next to the bower.json as apposed to in the dev folder like I've defined in the .bowerrc file like so

```
{
  "directory": "dev/bower_components"
}
```

When I run `bower install` after yeoman is done it installs the bower_components folder in the dev folder like it should.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've looked through a few things and can't see a definite answer but I suspect you will need to read the .bowerrc file and pass the directory in as an option to the bower.commands.install call. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Yeoman generator you use could force you to install deps on a certian specific path.

Open Terminal and go to the root directory of your app.
type `ls -la`.
if you see `.yo-rc.json`, type `cat .yo-rc.json`.

Does it show any particular config for the path like below?

```
{
  "generator-backbone-laser": {
    "appPath": "app"
  }
}
```

if so, delete `.yo-rc.json`.
a creator of Yoeman's generator sometimes set app path on that file.